# Microsoft Graph API: I get stuck in the authorization workflow

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get data from an Azure Active Directory that I created.
I want to retrieve this data through Microsoft's Graph API. I used one of the code samples that Microsoft provides to make HTTP GET Requests:

Config.py file:

```
"""Configuration settings for running the Python auth samples locally.

In a production deployment, this information should be saved in a database or
other secure storage mechanism.
"""


CLIENT_ID = 'Here I Pasted my application ID'

CLIENT_SECRET = 'Here I Pasted the key i generated'

REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/login/authorized'

# AUTHORITY_URL ending determines type of account that can be authenticated:
# /organizations = organizational accounts only
# /consumers = MSAs only (Microsoft Accounts - Live.com, Hotmail.com, etc.)
# /common = allow both types of accounts
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common'

AUTH_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

RESOURCE = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
SCOPES = ['User.Read.All'] # Add other scopes/permissions as needed.


# This code can be removed after configuring CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET above.
if 'ENTER_YOUR' in CLIENT_ID or 'ENTER_YOUR' in CLIENT_SECRET:
    print('ERROR: config.py does not contain valid CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET')
    import sys
    sys.exit(1)
```

sample_requests.py file:

```
"""Requests-OAuthlib sample for Microsoft Graph """
# Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
# See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
import os
import uuid

import bottle
import requests_oauthlib

import config

MSGRAPH = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(config.CLIENT_ID,
                                          scope=config.SCOPES,
                                          redirect_uri=config.REDIRECT_URI)

# Enable non-HTTPS redirect URI for development/testing.
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
# Allow token scope to not match requested scope. (Other auth libraries allow
# this, but Requests-OAuthlib raises exception on scope mismatch by default.)
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_IGNORE_SCOPE_CHANGE'] = '1'

bottle.TEMPLATE_PATH = ['./static/templates']

@bottle.route('/')
@bottle.view('homepage.html')
def homepage():
    """Render the home page."""
    return {'sample': 'Requests-OAuthlib'}

@bottle.route('/login')
def login():
    """Prompt user to authenticate."""
    auth_base = config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.AUTH_ENDPOINT
    authorization_url, state = MSGRAPH.authorization_url(auth_base)
    MSGRAPH.auth_state = state
    return bottle.redirect(authorization_url)

@bottle.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    """Handler for the application's Redirect Uri."""
    if bottle.request.query.state != MSGRAPH.auth_state:
        raise Exception('state returned to redirect URL does not match!')
    MSGRAPH.fetch_token(config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
                        client_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
                        authorization_response=bottle.request.url)
    return bottle.redirect('/graphcall')

@bottle.route('/graphcall')
@bottle.view('graphcall.html')
def graphcall():
    """Confirm user authentication by calling Graph and displaying some data."""
    endpoint = config.RESOURCE + config.API_VERSION + '/me'
    headers = {'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-requests-0.1.0',
               'x-client-SKU': 'sample-python-requests',
               'SdkVersion': 'sample-python-requests',
               'client-request-id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
               'return-client-request-id': 'true'}
    graphdata = MSGRAPH.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
    return {'graphdata': graphdata, 'endpoint': endpoint, 'sample': 'Requests-OAuthlib'}

@bottle.route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    """Handler for static files, used with the development server."""
    root_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    return bottle.static_file(filepath, root=os.path.join(root_folder, 'static'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bottle.run(app=bottle.app(), server='wsgiref', host='localhost', port=5000)
```

Source Code on Github [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth)

I receive the following problem. When I compile my code I go to the localhost on port 5000:

[image]

Then I hit connect and it takes me to the login interface. After I login with my Microsoft account (the same account I used to create the active directory and my registered app), it just displays this:

[image]

Whether I login with my Azure Account or any of the users I created in the active directory, it does not work.

My active directory is just one group called staff, and inside that group I have 3 users.

I would appreciate any comment,

thanks!

Comment: It has an error description in the URL of the "We're unable to..." window, can you add that?

Comment: @juunas oh sorry, sure. It says the following:

https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=1033#error=unauthorized_client&error_description=The+client+does+not+exist.+If+you+are+the+application+developer%2c+configure+a+new+application+through+the+application+management+site+at+https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/.&state=8KTdw8GkMVb4xC8RstBfOy7fn6MQ1e

Comment: Did you register the app in Azure Portal or the v2 app portal (apps.dev.microsoft.com)? Because I see you are using v2 endpoints. At the moment you need to use the other portal to register those.

Comment: @junnas with register you mean register it in the active directory?, hmmm i did it with the azure portal, in the "App Registration" section, thats how i obtained the token. Or should I register it with the other site that you sent me the link?

Comment: Yeah you need to use the other site. If you register it in Azure Portal, you need to use the v1 endpoints.

Comment: @juunas oh thank you so much!, hmm if i would like to change the endpoints to V1 endpoints, what should i change in my code?

Comment: Auth endpoint is `/oauth2/authorize`, remove the v2 part from the token endpoint too. Remove the scopes since v1 does not support that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174667/discussion-between-jplaudir8-and-juunas).